# Add css to existing applied css based on condition in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a style const variable,

```
const style = {
  timeInput: {
    width: '3.75rem',
    outline: 'none',
    borderColor: 'transparent',
    fontSize: remCalc(12),
    color: darkestGrey
  },
}
```

Here is the input field,

```
<input
  style={style.timeInput} //here
  disabled={disabled}
  ref={instance => (this.dropDown = instance)}
  value={typeof time === 'string' ? time : moment(time).format('LT')}
  onChange={this.onTimeChange.bind(this)}
></input>
```

How can I add `"opacity: '0.4'"` css, when disabled is true ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new object with the property added to it. Before the JSX for that input:

```
let inputStyle = style.timeInput;
if (disabled) {
    inputStyle = {...inputStyle, opacity: "0.4"};
}
```

then use `inputStyle` instead of `style.timeInput` on the element.

---

If you like, you can avoid the `if`, but at the *(very, very, very small)* cost of creating an unnecessary object:

```
const inputStyle = {...style.timeInput, ...(disabled ? {opacity: "0.4"} : null)};
```

That works because spreading `null` is a no-op.

Comment: @Clarity - Doh! Thanks. :-)